# NewtonSoft Json tests failing

Tags: json.net

I have downloaded the source code from Newtonsoft Json, version 13.0.3 ,  It compiles fine, however 3 tests are failing it is the same stack tracek XmlNode_EncodeSpecialCharacters

1. Failed : Newtonsoft.Json.Tests.Converters.XmlNodeConverterTest.XmlNode_EncodeSpecialCharacters
   Expected string length 768 but was 804. Strings differ at index 1.
   Expected: "{\n  "?xml": {\n    "@version": "1.0",\n    "@standalone": "no"\n..."
   But was:  "{\r\n  "?xml": {\r\n    "@version": "1.0",\r\n    "@standalone": "n..."
   -------------^
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Tests.Converters.XmlNodeConverterTest.XmlNode_EncodeSpecialCharacters() in D:\Development\NewtonSoft Json\Newtonsoft.Json-release-13.0.3\Src\Newtonsoft.Json.Tests\Converters\XmlNodeConverterTest.cs:line 279

it seems to me there are extra "\r" in the output

tests run successfully for the released source code.

Comment: Seems like an inconsistency in newline characters between the actual and expected JSON.  Your expected newline was `\n` but the actual newline was `\r\n`.  The NewLine used comes from [`TextWriter.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.newline?view=net-7.0) (see the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs#L340) for confirmation) so you need to examine the test code to see why the newline is inconsistent.

Comment: i have traced the call, it seems the caller is JsonConvert.cs in SerializeObjectInternal(object? value, Type? type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) method. where a StringWriter is created without setting newline which then uses the default newLIne setting \r\n.  The behavior is different in version 13.03 , earlier version i was using was 6.xx.